# Nested Routing in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-router

Hello All Angular2 Developers,

Here is a challenge I am facing and not knowing how to resolve it.

I have my app.component.ts file as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import { LeftMenuComponent } from './left-menu.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';
import {TotalContainer} from './container-total.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <myheader [display]="display"></myheader>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives:[HeaderComponent,TotalContainer,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { 
    display = true;
}
```

I have written all the view of the header in header.component and loaded in HTML. In the "header.component", I am loading the "left-menu.component". In the left-menu.component, I am having hyperlinks which are to be loaded in the "app.component".

The error that I am getting is that there is "No provider for the router".

I continued basing upon the angular.io sample but could not solve it.

Here is how I wrote the code.
header.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {LeftMenuComponent} from './left-menu.component';

@Component({
    selector:'myheader',
    template:`
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div>
             ....
            </div>
        </nav>
        <left-menu [class.disp]="display"></left-menu>

    `,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LeftMenuComponent]
})
export class HeaderComponent{
    @Input() display;
}
```

left-menu.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {KeyEventsPlugin} from '@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events';

@Component({
    selector:'left-menu',
    template:`
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
                <span class="badge">14</span>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/followups']" routerLinkActive="active-link">Follow Ups</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class LeftMenuComponent{

}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import {FollowUpsComponent} from '../components/followups.component';
import {TotalContainer} from '../components/container-total.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path:'total-container',
        component:TotalContainer
    },
    {
        path:'followups',
        component: FollowUpsComponent,
    },
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'/total-container',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path:'**',
        redirectTo:'/total-container'
    }
];


export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';

import { appRouterProviders } from './routes/app.routes'; 
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    appRouterProviders
]); 

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Can anyone help me with this.a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main.ts it looks like you call bootstrap twice accidentally:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';

import { appRouterProviders } from './routes/app.routes'; 
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    appRouterProviders
]); 

bootstrap(AppComponent); <-----delete this!
```

Delete the second one and you should be good to go

Comment: That's it. Wow. Thanks very much.